# Brezis Functional Analysis Exercise 2.10

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Hi I'm trying the following exercise from the book.

Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces and let $T\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ be surjective

1. Let $M$ be any subset of $E$. Prove that $T(M)$ is closed in F iff $M+N(T)$ is closed in $E$.

I'm stuck with the converse.

The hint from the book says that since $T$ is surjective then
$$
T((M+N(T))^c)=(T(M))^c.
$$

But I don't understand why, since the property says that if a function $f$ is surjective then
$$
(f(A))^c \subset f(A^c).
$$
Could anyone explain me? Or give another hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For any function $f \colon X \to Y$ and any subset $B$ of $Y$,
  $$
  f^{-1}(B^c) = f^{-1}(B)^c.
  $$
- For any surjective function $f \colon X \to Y$ and any subset $B$ of $Y$,
  $$
  f(f^{-1}(B)) = B.
  $$
- If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the same field, then for any linear map $L \colon V \to W$ and any subspace $S$ of $V$,
  $$
  L^{-1}(L(S)) = S+N(L).
  $$

These are easy exercises that has nothing to do with functional analysis.

So, if $M+N(T) = T^{-1}(T(M))$ is closed in $E$, then
$$
(M+N(T))^c = T^{-1}(T(M)^c)
$$
is open in $E$, and so
$$
T((M+N(T))^c) = T(T^{-1}(T(M)^c)) = T(M)^c
$$
is open in $F$ since $T$ is surjective.